# quadratic in linear form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

- $y = mx + b$ is a linear equation and represents a straight line. (The direction $m$ is constant.)
- $y = x^2 + b$ is quadratic and represents a parabola. (The direction of the tangent is not constant.)
- But $y = x^2 = x\cdot x$ in linear form with the first $x$ being the direction and y intercept being $0$ in this case.

So you could say that indeed the direction depends upon $x$.

However, for $x = 1$, $m = 2$ and not $1$ and indeed the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$.

Why? Where does the $2$ come from?

Comment: First of all `y=x*x` is NOT in linear form because `x` is not constant like `m`

Comment: How did you learn derivates ? As a limit of the difference-quotient ?

Comment: thanks across, I understand that, the question is: at each point you could interpret it as being fixed (linear approximation)

Comment: hey Peter, thanks for your answer, but the derivative is just to mention the correct answer; I would like to keep it out

Comment: Ok to see where the `2` comes from may be try to simplify $$\dfrac{x^2-1^2}{x-1}$$. Then see what happens as $x$ goes close to $1$

Comment: I understand the derivative; the question is about what is wrong with the above logic

Comment: Hmm ok I think I see your point. you seem to be suggesting that the derivative of $y = \color{blue}{x}*x$ is $\color{blue}{x}$ because it looks like $y=\color{blue}{m}x$. By same reasoning what is the derivative of $y=\color{blue}{x^2}*x$ ?

Comment: @MuseOfMusic The problem is that you simply can't "interpret [one of the $x$'s] as being fixed". You need to take into account that both $x$'s grow; since they do! However, you are still a little bit right: The two results differ only by a constant factor (namely $2$), so the approximation (let's call it that) is not so very bad. But still wrong.

Comment: yes idd @across; why is the direction of tangent on x^2 * x not = to x^2?

Comment: the point is basically: what happens 'inside' a quadratic compared to a linear equation? what is so different between a constant and a fixed variable value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both the terms in the product $\color{blue}{x}*x$ are changing with $x$, you must use the product rule:

$$\color{blue}{x}*x$$
For a small change in $x$'s :
$$ (\color{blue}{x+\Delta x})*(x+\Delta x)$$

Take the difference
$$(\color{blue}{x+\Delta x})*(x+\Delta x) - \color{blue}{x}*x$$
Simplifying gives
$$\color{blue}{x}*\Delta x + \color{blue}{\Delta x}*x + \color{blue}{\Delta x}\Delta x$$

Divide by $\Delta x$
$$\color{blue}{x} + x + \Delta x$$

Since $\Delta x$ goes to $0$ as the secant approaches the tangent... see where  the $2x$ comes from?

Comment: thanks very much for your explanation; idd as I see it a constant does not contribute to 'next value down the line', but a variable of course does

Comment: Yes if it were just $f(x)=mx$, then for a small change $\Delta x$ in $x$, the function  becomes $f(x+\Delta x) = m(x+\Delta x)$, the difference is $f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) = m(x+\Delta x) - mx$; simplifying, then divide by $\Delta x$ yields $m$. I found this way of reasoning  helpful when I first started learning calculus. Hope it helps you too. Enjoy..